# How can I add a User (Or Group) to a SharePoint-Group (just view) with different Names?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, permissions

my english is not the best. But I hope you can understand me clearly.

To my question:

We have one SharePoint with many different SiteCollections with different users and permissions. Last week was decided that a specially AD-Group should add to all visitor-groups of all SiteCollections. How can I do that with PowerShell?

I am a beginner and tried many codes, but I not get it. Because every group has their own name -> Visitors of [-Name]. How is this implemented?

Summary:

- One AD-Group shall be a member of each Visitor-Group of each SiteCollection (with different names).

In the best case the code can add exceptions for some SiteCollections. (But thats not a must).

I would be happy if you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the default visitor group from a site by accessing this property:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.associatedvisitorgroup?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_SPWeb_AssociatedVisitorGroup

You would need to add the AD group to it and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out .

Get your web application .

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://example.com"

Load all site collections under that web application .

$siteColls = Get-SPSite -webapplication $web -limit all

foreach($siteColl in $siteColls)

{

$siteCollWeb = Get-SPweb $siteColl.url

$visitorsGroup = $siteCollWeb.associatedVisitorsgroup

}

This will get you the default visitors group created by default when the site got created.